# PHP: Export to CSV with special characters

Tags: php, csv, export, character

I am trying to export some data that is stored on a table but when I tried to export to CSV this letter č shows like Ä or &#269.

I tried everithing utf8_decode, utf8_enconde, html_entity_decode, but is not working. What can I do?

Thanks,
Leandro.

Additional Information: Now I directly testing the following:

```
$delimiter = ";";
$enclosure = '"';

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=memorandos.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

$header = array('Apellido');
fputcsv($output, $header, $delimiter, $enclosure);
$memorando = Memorando::getById(3263);
if ($memorando){
    $dd = array ();
    $dd[] = $memorando->apellido;   ////ON THE DATABSE IS STORED LIKE Jurič
    fputcsv($output, $dd, $delimiter, $enclosure);
}
```

On the file I see this Juri&#269 ; instead of Jurič

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems have you run into?
Please read [How to ask questions on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: don't change the character, change the page\file encoding

Answer (score 0):

There are many angles and approaches of dealing with this issue, you can even try: ISO-8859-1

Lets say you have

```
$input = "Fóø Bår Zacarías ?S?B?D Ferreíra"; // original text
```

Use iconv to get rid of the special chars

```
$output = iconv("utf-8", "ascii//TRANSLIT//IGNORE", $input);
```

Regexp lets remove utf-8 special characters except blank spaces

```
$output =  preg_replace("/^'|[^A-Za-z0-9\s-]|'$/", '', $output);
```

Results in: Foo Bar Zacarias ASABAD Ferreira

```
echo $output;
```

And where is your code? can you share?

Comment: I shared my latest test. Thanks for the response but with that solution the character is converted from č to c and I need to see č. Thanks.